# warning in daisy function in R

Tags: r, warnings, r-daisy

I have used the daisy function to calculate the distance, but it encounters the following warning:

```
In cluster::daisy(mixusefull2) :binary variable(s) 6 treated as interval 
scaled
```

My data and their types are as follows:

```
str(mixusefull2)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  10 variables:
$ protocol_type              : Factor w/ 3 levels "icmp","tcp","udp": 2 2
$ service                    : Factor w/ 63 levels 
"auth","bgp","courier",..: 20 20
$ src_bytes                  : int  315 330
$ count                      : int  5 6
$ srv_count                  : int  5 6
$ diff_srv_rate              : num  0 0
$ dst_host_srv_count         : int  255 255
$ dst_host_same_srv_rate     : num  1 1
$ dst_host_diff_srv_rate     : num  0 0
$ dst_host_same_src_port_rate: num  0 0
```

Why does this warning show me?
please help me.thank you

Comment: Do you only have two rows (obs.) in the data?

Comment: I want to continuously calculate the distance between each data with the rest of the data, and then the first data will be deleted. This procedure will continue until the end of the data.
For example, suppose we have 10 data. In the first step, the daisy function is calculated for the first data with 9 data.
Then the first data will be deleted.
In the next step, the daisy function is calculated for the next data with 8 data, and so to the end.For this reason (mixusefull2) contains 2 samples. Since I wrote str (mixusefull2) in the end. please help me.thank you